# does anyone have experience with the on form submission trigger creating an error code: "Exception: Event start time must be before event end time"

Tags: google-calendar-api, eventtrigger

I am including the script ( below), the [trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTIUt.jpg), the [sample of the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYM5a.jpg), image of the [start and end time formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv3Ep.png)  and the error(below)...

When I run the createCalendarEvent script manually...no issues..it is when i try to automate the script by creating an event trigger for on form submit that I get the following error:

> Error Exception: Event start time must be before event end time.
> at createCalendarEvent(create event:26:16)

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var calendar = 
CalendarApp.getCalendarById("c_71lju3i096qeqsg69bd7togo9g@group.calendar.google.com");

var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process - 2 exempts my header row
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-1, numColumns);
var data = dataRange.getValues();

var complete = "Done";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var startTime = new Date(row[0]);  //start Time
var endTime = new Date(row[1]); //end Time
var title = row[2]; //Item Title
var option = row[3]; //event option
var location = row[4]; //location
var eventID = row[6]; //event marked Done


if (eventID != complete) {
  var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, numColumns);
  calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, {description:  option + '\r' , location: 
location});

  currentCell.setValue(complete);
}
}
}
```

I have edited the original script and included the trigger just in the script itself ( By passing the automated trigger creation)...this way worked....1 time!..now i get the following error.

> Exception: Action not allowed setUpTrigger @ create event.gs5

```
function setUpTrigger() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger('createCalendarEvent')
.forForm('1FAIpQLScQvxc8EUSjGvrrVc6-QE3LwNZOytetIrfOVX-RKrJwS8_ALw')
.onFormSubmit()
.create();
}

function createCalendarEvent() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("c_71lju3i096qeqsg69bd7togo9g@group.calendar.google.com");

var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process - 2 exempts my 
header row
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-1, numColumns);
var data = dataRange.getValues();

var complete = "Done";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var startTime = new Date(row[0]);  //start Time
var endTime = new Date(row[1]); //end Time
var title = row[2]; //Item Title
var option = row[3]; //event option
var location = row[4]; //location
var eventID = row[6]; //event marked Done


if (eventID != complete) {
  var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, numColumns);
  calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, {description:  
option + '\r' , location: location});

  currentCell.setValue(complete);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include some test data that does throw this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty self explanatory.

> Error Exception: Event start time must be before event end time

Check the values you are sending for start and end time. Make sure that the event does not end before it starts.

```
var startTime = new Date(row[0]);  //start Time
var endTime = new Date(row[1]); //end Time
```

Comment: that would be the obvious answer, however if you look at the sample of the spreadsheet that is included, all of the end times submitted , definitely end after the submitted start times.

Comment: if that is the case for all of them then i would check the formatting to ensure that drive is parsing it properly.  Google is not lying to you.   You have a end date before a start date.  May i suggest you check the formatting of the day month to ensure its not parsing them backwards.   Unless you can give me an exact case where you are sending  of a start and end date that is doing this i would still say its your dats.

Comment: I appreciate the response, however the start and end dates are formatted as:
year, month, day, hour ,minute. I have also updated all time zones to correspond with each other ( sheets, forms, script)...on a side not...if i run the create calendar event manually, it works with no issues..it is only when attempting to have it automatically run with the creation of the event trigger on form submit

Comment: What about the column in sheets you are using is that formated as a date?

Comment: yes. Thank you for that, I did double check, and yes the columns are formatted correctly as date, same as the cells

Comment: Can you tell me exactly which line is failing.  what dates?  I want to test it myself.

Comment: hello, The createCalendarEvent function does work when run manually, it specifically just does not work when trying to automate using an installable trigger such as on form submit. I was able to get the onFormsubmit to function properly one time by installing the trigger in the script and bypassing the create trigger page , however after the one successful operation, it now provides the error every time and does not function, it's is not one specific line, or date, it just does not work period when trying to automate